# QWidget::show() with a set parent

Tags: qt, qt5

Is it expected behaviour that `QDialog::show()` does not show the window if a parent has been set?

Background: I want to use `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName()` to react to one of the dialogs signals, which means the parent-object needs to own it. Without the line marked as "*This is the line in question*" I get a runtime-message "*QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_child_accepted()*". But with the line, the child dialog no longer appears.

```
#include <QtCore/QDebug>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QDialog>
#include <QtWidgets/QPushButton>
#include <QtWidgets/QVBoxLayout>

class Parent : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Parent(QWidget *parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = Qt::WindowFlags())
        : QDialog{parent, f}
    {
        b.setText(tr("Show child"));
        connect(&b, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() {
            c.show();
        });
        l.addWidget(&b);
        setLayout(&l);

        c.setParent(this);  // This is the line in question
        c.setObjectName("child");
        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(this);
    }

private slots:
    void on_child_accepted()
    {
        qDebug() << "I got called";
    }

private:
    QPushButton b;
    QDialog c;
    QVBoxLayout l;
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Parent w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This test fails on Qt 5.11 for Windows, from the MSYS2 64-bit build.

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog did actually appear, but not where you think it did: it is a non-window child widget of your window - it was transparent and yet it obscured most of the "Show Dialog" button, consuming all mouse events, and furthermore it was already shown since all children are shown when the parent is shown - so the button appeared to be non-functional for both of those reasons.

Setting a widget's parent clears its `Qt::Window` flag. Setting the dialog's background helps visualize the problem. Thus, you need to make the dialog a window after setting its parent.

The following reproduces your bug, and also demonstrates the fix.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/dialog-show-parenting-53208641
#include <QtWidgets>
class Parent : public QDialog {
   Q_OBJECT
   QVBoxLayout layout{this};
   QDialog child;
   QPushButton cShow{tr("Show child")}, cNonWindow{tr("Renew non-window child")},
       cWindow{tr("Renew window child")};
   Q_SLOT void on_child_accepted() {}
   void reChild(bool makeWindow) {
      child.~QDialog();
      new (&child) QDialog;
      Q_ASSERT(child.isWindow());
      child.setParent(this);
      child.setObjectName("child");
      child.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background: blue }");
      if (makeWindow) {
         child.setWindowFlag(Qt::Dialog);
         Q_ASSERT(child.isWindow());
      } else {
         Q_ASSERT(!child.isWindow());
         child.show();  // The child gets shown when we're shown
      }
      QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, &Parent::updateChild, Qt::QueuedConnection);
   }
   void updateChild() {
      if (!child.isWindow()) child.move(50, cWindow.y() + cWindow.height() / 2);
      this->update();  // Work around a refresh bug (affects OS X on 5.11 at least)
   }

  public:
   Parent(QWidget *parent = nullptr, Qt::WindowFlags f = {}) : QDialog{parent, f} {
      connect(&cShow, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]() { child.show(); });
      connect(&cNonWindow, &QPushButton::clicked, [&] { reChild(false); });
      connect(&cWindow, &QPushButton::clicked, [&] { reChild(true); });
      for (auto *w : {&cShow, &cNonWindow, &cWindow}) layout.addWidget(w);
      cNonWindow.click();
      QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(this);
   }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   Parent w;
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Very nice! And appart from the original question, I also learned a bit about placement-new...